# How can I find the corresponding type of a given key of T?

Tags: typescript

Apologies for the title, having trouble making it clearer.

Let's say I have a class `Person`:

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

And another class `FormControl`:

```
class FormControl<T> {
  constructor(
    public key: keyof T,
    public value: any // What should value's type be?
  ) {}
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to create an instance of the `FormControl` class as such...

```
new FormControl<Person>('name', 'Bob');
```

Where the `key` property ***must*** be a key of `T`, and the `value` property ***must*** be the ***corresponding*** type of the given key of `T`.

Simply having `keyof T` works great for the `key` field, but I am not sure how to approach the type for the `value` field.

Is this possible with Typescript? Or is there another way to achieve something similar to this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this because the type information disappears after compilation finishes. It's not quite so cut and dried as that if you're willing to limit the argument to constructor to a string constant but if it's an arbitrary runtime string there's simply no way to do it no matter how advanced the compiler gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript has property access notation `Index[Key]` for retrieving the type of the value specified for the corresponding key in an index type:

```
type PersonName = Person['name']; // string
type PersonAge = Person['age']; // number
```

You can use this to constrain the constructor like so:

```
class FormControl<T, K extends keyof T> {
  constructor(
    public key: K,
    public value: T[K],
  ) {}
}
```

Unfortunately, TS doesn't allow you to specify only a subset of generic type parameters, so you'll have to specify both generics:

```
new FormControl<Person, 'name'>('name', 'Bob');
new FormControl<Person, 'age'>('age', 'five'); // TypeError - expected number
```

You can work around this using a curried function, but the syntax is a bit awkward:

```
const formControlFactory = <T extends any>() =>
  <K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) =>
    new FormControl(key, value);

const personFCFactory = formControlFactory<Person>();
personFCFactory('name', 'Bob');
personFCFactory('age', 'five'); // TypeError - expected number
```

You can read the discussion on specifying only a subset of generic type parameters [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16597).

Comment: I wish I had refreshed this page sooner cause I just figured it out, but thank you for the great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the great answer superhawk610!

Rather than using that factory, I am using another class's constructor to group the `FormControl` instances together, which also removes the need to specify both generics:

```js
class FormControlGroup<T> {
  constructor(
    public controls: FormControl<T, any>[]
  ) {}
}
```

Not sure if I should be using `any` as the second generic, but it seems to work.

`FormControlGroup` in use:

```js
new FormControlGroup<Person>([
  new FormControl('name', 'Bob'),
  new FormControl('age', 'eleventeen') // TypeError - expected number
])
```